# How to add the action bar for Android 2.1 and above?

Tags: android

when i add the library folder and follow the steps on the developer site, and later type "extends ActionBarActivity", it says ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved type. what else should i do for it to be perfect? i am a first time developer with no experience at all, so please answer

Comment: Are you using eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: does anyone even use a 2.1 device anymore?

Comment: @tyczj i'm talking about people who use versions between 2.1 and 3.0. that includes 2.3 users, which have almost 25% of the Android market.

Comment: add actionbarcompat library project in your workspace...then right click your project and add the library. Then clean and build

Answer (score 0):

You need to import ActionBarActivity. While looking at the Activity, press Ctrl+Shift+o
It can't resolve the Class because it's not imported yet. This simple keyboard shortut will greatly come in handy when you use a new Class that is not imported into the page yet. As for some documentation on this, checkout [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Comment: i dont understand the 'looking' part

Comment: Just have that file open in Eclipse

Comment: you mean the library file or the project file? both are open in mine

Comment: I mean the Activity you are seeing the error in. Just open it and press Ctrl+shift+o. If you are this new to Java you should learn about imports and what they are

Comment: the shortcut isn't working, should i type "import android.app.ActionBarActivity"?

Comment: Yes, that does the same thing. I was just trying to make it easier. If you're new to Android, I like Android Studio much more than Eclipse. It has a smaller user base, but much greater functionality for Android development. It's also still in beta, but excellent